# Float Array input to Display For Android

Tags: android, arrays, opengl-es

I'm trying to make a very simple cad program for android using opengl. So i'm trying to figure out how to input x,y,z float values from edit text view to an array. This is my code to start, it was going to display the float array to text view but when i run the app i enter the number in then it crashes.

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
    final EditText inPut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    final View display =(View ) findViewById(R.id.display);
    final View Info =(View) findViewById(R.id.info);

    bline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = 0;
            final float[] line = new float[10000];


        ((TextView) Info).setText("Point 1");
        float coords = Float.valueOf(inPut.getText().toString());
        for (i=0;i<line.length-1;i++){
            line[i]=coords;
            }

         ((TextView) display).setText(String.valueOf(line[i]));


        }
    });`
```

Comment: Ok I figured it out But now when i enter the values in and hit the button i get:    0.0/ Point 1  I also updated the code Above.

Comment: It is because you populate the first 9999 elements of your array (of 10000) with the coords value (You now stop at length-2: you should put in the condition i<line.length). Do you really need an array of 10000 elements, all with the same value? Then you show in the TextView the value of the element 10000 (at index 9999, that you have not initialized). So you should give to i a value between 0 and 9998 if you want to show the coord value in the TextView.

Comment: No i dont need them all with the same value i was trying to make the index and add the coords to the index so if i entered 0.0: the index would be [1]=0.0, [2]=12.32,[3]=1.3 .... so on and so forth so the program would increase the index by 1 each time the button was pressed and add coords to that index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array of float has size 0, because you instantiate it with:

```
final float[] line = new float[i];
```

where i is initialized to 0. Then you try to assign the location line[0] a value, but line[0] does not exists. Furthermore in your for loop you should stop when i is equal to length-1, not to length, otherwise you will get an IndexOutOfRange Exception:

```
 for (i=0;i<line.length;i++){
    line[i]=coords;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ((TextView) display).setText((int) (line[i]=coords));
```

here is your problem. YOu are trynt to use setText(int resId) method and that string id does not exist. Change it in

```
 line[i] = coords;
 ((TextView) display).setText(String.valueOf(line[i]));
```

Comment: the stacktrace? is R.id.line declared inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: I  forgot to check the logcat for any error messages so ill do that when i get home and ill post that here if it would help.